# How can I reinitialize some MyISAM tables without restarting MySQL?

Tags: mysql, myisam

I'm using `rsync` to copy some measurement data from one PC to the server.

Is it possible to load the new MyISAM tables without restarting the MySQL server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Absolutely !!!

Suppose you are moving a MyISAM table with the following characteristics:

- MyISAM table is called `mydb.mytable`
- `datadir` is `/var/lib/mysql`
- Moving From `ServerA` to `ServerB`

You can move it to another folder without disturbing any other DB activity

Here is how

Step01) Create the Target Database on ServerB with this command

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb;
```

Step02) Copy the table to the `mydb` database on `ServerB`

Run this rsync on ServerA

```
rsync -av --progress /var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytable.* ServerB:/var/lib/mysql/mydb
```

That's it. The table should be immediate registered in the information_schema without a restart. To verify that the rsync worked, login to mysql on ServerB and run this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) TableExists FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema='mydb' AND table_name='mytable';
SELECT table_rows TableCount1 FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema='mydb' AND table_name='mytable';
SELECT COUNT(1) TableCount2 FROM mydb.mytable;
```

If `TableExists` is 1 and  TableCount1 =  TableCount2, CONGRATULATIONS !!!

If you want to double check the rsync, run thi command on both `ServerA` and `ServerB`

```
CHECKSUM TABLE mydb.mytable;
```

Both checksum values should be identical

Give it a Try !!!