# Fastest way to set up MySQL replication from backup

Tags: mysql, replication, backup

Here's my scenario:

- I have a single database on network A that needs to be transferred to network B.
- on network B, I need a master-slave setup with 2/3 slaves.
- I need to run some significant updates / deletions to the database before it can be put into production again This will probably take a few hours.
- Most importantly, I need to minimize downtime.

My current plan is to:

- turn off MySQL
- backup the MySQL datadir
- run my scripts to update the database to the new schema
- rsync the entire datadir to all master/slave servers on network B

At this point I have exact copies of the data on all servers. From what I've read, I should then be able to extract the binlog status and start replication.

Does this sound like a reasonable plan, or am I missing something obvious that would a) rule this out or b) make this easier / faster?

Comment: Sounds good, maybe http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12092/how-to-resolve-the-master-server-shut-down-unavailability-in-mysql-with-master helps you?

Answer (score 1):

For the Sake of this Post

- IP of Master is 10.20.30.100
- IP of Slave1 is 10.20.30.110
- IP of Slave2 is 10.20.30.120
- IP of Slave3 is 10.20.30.130

## ALL InnoDB

If all your tables are InnoDB, you can do this:

**STEP 01** : If you do not have binary logging enabled, you need to enable it. Here is how you can tell:

Login to MySQL and run this

```
mysql> SHOW MASTER STATUS;
```

If you get something like this:

```
mysql> show master status;
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB | Executed_Gtid_Set |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| mysql-bin.000266 |      120 |              |                  |                   |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

then, it is enabled. If you get Empty Set, then it is not enabled.

To enable it, add this to your `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
log-bin=mysql-bin
```

and restart mysql

**STEP 02** : Create a Replication User on the Master

Run this

```
GRANT REPLICATION CLIENT,REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.*
TO replicator@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'replicationpass';
```

**STEP 03** : Test the Replication User

On each of the Slaves, run this in Linux

```
MASTER_IP=10.20.30.100
mysql -h${MASTER_IP} -ureplicator -preplicationpass -ANe"SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'hostname'"
```

Make sure it echos the hostname of the Master from all Slaves.

**STEP 04** : Clear all binary logs on the Master

Simply run

```
mysql> RESET MASTER;
```

To clear away all binary logs and start with a fresh one

**STEP 05** : Dump all your data to a text file

From

```
MASTER_IP=10.20.30.100
echo "CHANGE MASTER TO master_host='${MASTER_IP}'," > LoadSlaveData.sql
echo "master_post=3306,master_user='replicator'," >> LoadSlaveData.sql
echo "master_password='replicationpass'," >> LoadSlaveData.sql
echo "master_log_file='bogus'," >> LoadSlaveData.sql
echo "master_log_pos=2;" >> LoadSlaveData.sql
DUMP_OPTIONS="-single-transaction --master_data=1 --routines --triggers"
mysqldump --uroot -p ${DUMP_OPTIONS} --all-databases >> LoadSlaveData.sql
echo "START SLAVE;" >> LoadSlaveData.sql
```

Line 28 will have the binary log and position for replication because of `--master_data=1`.

**STEP 06** : Load the SQL file into each Slave

Login to Each Slave and Load that File

```
mysql -h10.20.30.110 -uroot -p < LoadSlaveData.sql
mysql -h10.20.30.120 -uroot -p < LoadSlaveData.sql
mysql -h10.20.30.130 -uroot -p < LoadSlaveData.sql
```

**THAT'S IT. NO DOWNTIME**

## ALL MYISAM or SOME InnoDB / SOME MyISAM

What you proposed in your question is more of a fit for databases with any MyISAM tables

I have recommended the same technique over the years

- `Nov 09, 2012` : [How can I reinitialize some MyISAM tables without restarting MySQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28367/how-can-i-reinitialize-some-myisam-tables-without-restarting-mysql/28411#28411)
- `Jul 24, 2012` : [How to copy a MySQL database which is a mixture of InnoDB and MyISAM to the same server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21419/how-to-copy-a-mysql-database-which-is-a-mixture-of-innodb-and-myisam-to-the-same/21420#21420)
- `Mar 15, 2012` : [Why is mysqlhotcopy slower compared to rsync?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15115/why-is-mysqlhotcopy-slower-compared-to-rsync/15116#15116)
- `Jun 17, 2011` : [What is the difference between XtraBackup and rsync?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3354/what-is-the-difference-between-xtrabackup-and-rsync/3356#3356)

I even mentioned this in StackOverflow : [**MySql - create replication with minimal downtime**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491953/mysql-create-replication-with-minimal-downtime/8493771#8493771)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Yes, we have a mixture of InnoDB and MyISAM, although we may be able to switch completely to InnoDB when upgrading schema. I'll have a read through the links.